# Best approach to create a "settings" dialog page in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I need to present the user with a **screen with controls** (i.e. a dialog). It will display some labels and different types of controls so that the user can do some configuration:

- select a color (custom color picker)
- select a line width (slider)
- select one value from a list of values (UISegmentedControl?)
- enable / disable one option (On/Off)
  ...

I am evaluating different alternatives:

1. Create the layout with labels and controls in **InterfaceBuilder**
2. Use a **UITableView**, so that each cell contains a label and its control

I like option 2 because it is similar to iPhone Settings app, and it makes the screen look organized, giving you sections, scroll..., but it is a real pain to create in code all different cell layouts, taking into account each row heights...

The solution has to be easiliy maintainable, allowing easy reuse of code, DRY (low repetition), data-driven...

Is there a recommended or standard aproach to do this?

Comment: why aren't you using the default setting functionality provided by the sdk framework?

Comment: it's not an apps settings page (preferences). The user can configure these properties for several items in the application

Answer (score 3):

Instead of implementing it yourself you might also like to consider some of the open source solutions. I use [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) in my app. There are a few minor UI glitches but it works well. I also evaluated [mySettings](http://bitbucket.org/karemorstol/mysettings/wiki/Home) (indeed I submitted a couple of patches) and [InAppSettings](http://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home).

Even if you don't use them, you might be able to crib a few ideas from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the tableview cells in IB and then just create IBOutlets to each cell, and then return each cell in the data source method (forgotten the exact name of it, its where you normally create cells)

You could create a cell in IB for each cell or create different types of cells in IB, say one slider based cell, etc and programmatically change the text, etc.

This is staticly creating a tableview, theres an Apple guide on it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you said it. use a UITableView and create custom UITableViewCells (probably in Interface Builder!) and add these in.
 Also, as far as selecting a value from a list of values.. a drill in UITableView (embed the root UITableView in a navigation controller) with all the options and then a checkmark is probably advisable (this is how most apps handle this behavior).  The On/Off button is more suited for UISegmentedControl.

There are great examples of this in [this book](http://apress.com/book/view/1430216263).

Good luck.